# Android activity with intent action.SEND gets uri which cannot be open?

Tags: android

Activity is defined as:

```
    <activity android:name="com.tralev.android.UploadFromCameraAppActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

UploadFromCameraAppActivity is trying to get URI:

```
Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
String filename = uri.getPath();
```

But when trying to open that filename I get exception:

03-12 23:10:30.787: W/System.err(9840): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/2437: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Note: This happens on Nexus 7 which I'm using to test.

SOLVED: This problem is solved using

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solved using

```
  public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
   String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
   int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permission android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?